# Generic JMS Client with SSL connection capability

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ssl, jms

Currently, I have implemented a non-SSL secured client using the standard JMS API (only `javax.jms.*` classes). When supplied with specific product JAR and proper classnames, it is able to connect to any JMS server.

Is there a way how to implement such generic (vendor-independent) JMS client with SSL connection capabilities?

My research was not successful - I've found several examples implementing JMS with SSL (e.g. [Novell JMS](https://www.novell.com/documentation/extend5/Docs/help/MP/jms/tutorial/ssl-1.htm), [ActiveMQ](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_ESB_Enterprise/7.1/html/ActiveMQ_Security_Guide/files/FMQSecuritySSLClients.html)) but none of them avoids using the vendor-specific classes directly in code and implementations differ considerably.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Using SSL doesn't require any code change in client. Adding SSL capability is only matter of configuration.**

In general, there are few things that will differ:

1. **Connection URL** so the client connects over SSL protocol to proper port (`ssl://broker_url` instead of `tcp://broker_url`).
2. **Connection factory class** - may be different from non-SSL one.
3. **Keystore** and/or **truststore** to be used. Paths to these files may be set programmatically using specific methods – but this approach requires vendor specific code to be implemented. Better option is to pass the KS/TS java system properties. (This can be done even without any preparation using the `-D` JVM option.)

Since points 2. and 3. differ from one JMS broker to another, see your vendor's documentation for further details.

---

This answer is based on experience with successful connection to Apache ActiveMQ and Tibco EMS, including mutual certificate authentication.